# How to allow a user to enter in multiple strings into an array until the Letter "q" is typed

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string

I am working on a Homework problem and just need some assistance in this one area. I am not asking for you to do my homework for me, just need some help, as I cannot find any additional information on the web.

I have created an Overload method that takes a string array as its parameter. I believe I created the method correctly to allow me to let a user enter in multiple strings that would be stored into an array.

I am now working in the static void main and am having trouble thinking of the code that needs to be implemented to allow the user to enter in multiple strings, until the user inputs 'q' on its own line, in which it will show the user how many words they had just entered.

please see the code below. you will be able to see the overload method and the part that I am stuck on in the static void main, which is enclosed with asterisks.

Again, I am not asking you do my hw, I just need some assistance with this one part. Also, here is an example of what I need the program to do. thank you in advanced for your help.

> Enter several sentences, when done entering sentences, use q by itself on the last line.
>
> Hello, how are you?
>
> I'm fine, and you?
>
> Just fine, just fine.
>
> q
>
> There are 12 words in that text.
>
> Enter several sentences, when done entering sentences, use q by itself on the last line.
>
> q

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main Menu");
        Console.WriteLine("Choose from the following:");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Word Count" + "\n" + "2. Vowel Counting" + "\n" + "3. Exit");
        Console.Write("Enter your selection: ");
        int s1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if(s1 == 1)
        {
        Break:;
            Console.WriteLine("Word Counter Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("Choose from the following");
            Console.WriteLine("1. Count the word in one sentence" + "\n" +
                                "2. Count the word in a paragraph" + "\n" +
                                "3. Parent Menu");
            Console.Write("Enter your selection ");
            int s2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if(s2 == 1)
            {
                string sent1;

                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter a sentence (q to quit, d for default): ");
                    sent1 = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("There are " + Def1(sent1) + " words in the sentence: " + sent1);

                    if(sent1 == "d")
                    {
                        sent1 = "Hello";
                        Console.WriteLine("There are " + Def1(sent1) + " words in the sentence: " + sent1);
                    }
                    if(sent1 == "q")
                    {
                        goto Break;
                    }
                }
            }
            **if (s2 == 2)
            {
                string sent2;
                Console.WriteLine("Enter several sentences, when done entering" + 
                                    " sentences, use q by itself on the last line:");
                while(true)
                {
                    sent2 = Console.ReadLine();
                    if(sent2 == "q")
                    {
                       // Console.WriteLine("There are " +  + " words in that text");
                        break;**
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    static int Def1(string d1 = "Hello")
    {
        int countWords = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < d1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(d1[i - 1]) == true)
            {
                if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(d1[i]) == true ||
                    char.IsPunctuation(d1[i]))
                {
                    countWords++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (d1.Length > 2)
        {
            countWords++;
        }
        return countWords;

    }
    static int Def1(string[] d1)
    {
        var e = from a in d1 select a;
        int cnt1 = e.Count();

        return cnt1;
    }
    static int vow1(string v1)
    {
        char[] vowels = new char[] { 'a', 'A', 'e', 'E', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U' };
        int total = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < v1.Length; i++)
        {
            if(vowels.Contains(v1[i]))
            {
                total++;
            }
        }
        return total;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use ReadKey and append it to a string if its not q?

Comment: Any way you can give me an example of what that might look like @rohit I am trying that but not getting the results I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For counting number of words in several strings (paragraph) you can write the code like this

```
if (s2 == 2) //2. Count the word in a paragraph
{
    string senttence2;
    List<string> sentences = new List<string>();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter several sentences, when done entering" +
                        " sentences, use q by itself on the last line:");
    senttence2 = Console.ReadLine();
    while (senttence2 != "q")
    {
        sentences.Add(senttence2);
        senttence2 = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("There are " + GetWordCount(sentences) + " words in that text");
}
```

And this is the method (using `Linq`)

```
static int GetWordCount(IEnumerable<string> sentences)
{
    return sentences.Select(s => s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Count()).Sum();
}
```

Comment: @E_T_A if the answer helped you, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your loop can be something like this.

You need two variables. first one is temporary value that holds the user input. its value is compared against `q` inside while loop. until the temporary value is not equal to `q` we should continue looping and append value of `temp` to another string which must hold all the inputs (except last `q`).

```
if (s2 == 2)
{
    string temp = ""; 
    Console.WriteLine("Enter several sentences, when done entering" + 
                        " sentences, use q by itself on the last line:");
    string finalString = ""; // initial empty value
    while((temp = Console.ReadLine()) != "q") // assign input to temp and check its value
    {
        finalString += " " + temp; // temp was not `q` so append it to text.
    }
    Console.WriteLine(???); // explained later
}
```

Note that we added extra space for each appending `temp` to `finalstring` to make sure that words are separated at the end of line and start of next line.

What should be in `Console.WriteLine(???);`.

This can be done easily with [`Split`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/split) method. You can Split the `finalstring` by spaces and commas. and then check if it contains words or not.

```
var possibleWords = finalString.Split(new[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

`RemoveEmptyEntries` is just the option to remove empty items from result of split.

Now you have to check that each of these string items contains letters or not. if they contain letters we count it as word.

```
var letterCount = possibleWords.Count(x => x.Any(char.IsLetter));
```

The method `Count` counts when ever the `x => x.Any(char.IsLetter)` returns true.

`x.Any(char.IsLetter)` will return true when ever the string `x` contains at least one letter.

So you can print something like this.

```
Console.WriteLine("There are " + letterCount + " words in that text");
```

The better way to count letters would be to use Regexes but thats higher level than yours so i prefer not to put it here. Hope it helps.